# 3D matrix for staggering 5 ten degree wide bands of angle of incidence shifted by target wavelength and optical path difference in arithmetic series

Tags: optics, aircraft-design, electronic-filters

Today, we came up with the idea of creating a 3 dimensional matrix where I  simultaneously stagger 3 times 5 times 5 Fabry Perot band-reject interferometeric filters with ten degree wide bands of angle of incidence insensitivity , red, green or blue wavelength selectivity as well as optical path difference equal  0 degrees, 10 degrees, 20 degrees, and wavelength in arithmetic progression to cover the incidence angle range of 0 to 50 degrees, the spectrum from 450 nm to 750 nm and the optical path difference range of 0 to 40 microns.

```
In the diagram below, 

   deltapsi_0 = 0 degrees of phase delay 
   deltapsi_1 = 10 degrees of phase delay
   deltapsi_2 = 20 degrees of phase delay
   deltapsi_3 = 30 degrees of phase delay
```

As described in Coutinho et al's paper "Detection of Coherent Light in 
an Incoherent Background" with URL discovery.ucl.ac.uk/2670/1/2670.pdf, the purpose of the Fabry Perot interferometer is to measure the self-coherence function of the incident radiation to give an interferogram, and uses a narrow band filter to produce the  sinc envelope necessary to measure the change in position of the self-coherence function minimum.

In Coutinho et al's paper "Detection of Coherent Light in 
an Incoherent Background", the authors use an electro-mechanical scanning Michelson interferometer to measure the self-coherence function of the incident radiation. However, the use of an electro-mechanical scanning Michelson interferometer limits the tuning speed required to protect pilots from incoming laser pointer rays within an 100 microsecond interval.

However, in 1999,  Brazilian Navy Officer Coutinho and IEEE Fellow Griffith used a Fourier Transform to measure the position of the first minima of the self coherence function. The disadvantages of the Fourier transform are that it requires the processing of a large amount of data and a reference laser is required to calibrate the path difference.

Subsequently, in 2007, Brazilian Navy Officer  Coutinho and IEEE Fellow Griffith got rid of the Fourier transform by using Interferogram Phase Step Shift(IPSS) where an interferometer measures self-coherence in the vicinity of the first mimimum with a much shorter scan interval and a signal processing algorithm to extract the position of the phase step function discontinuity in the fringe carrier, proportional to self-coherence. The most problematic aspect of this is that it requires preknowledge of the coherent laser's spectral characteristics within a narrowband width.

In the 3 dimensional matrix block diagram shown below, we simultanously measure the self coherence function amplitude at 5 different optical pathlength  differences and curvefit a quintic polynomial function representing the self coherence function's sinc envelope for the purpose of measuring the change in position of the self-coherence function minimum. By doing the operation simulatenously and in parallel we hope to speed up the tuning speed.

@hsinghal pointed out to me that as far as Fabry-Perot filters are concerned they are highly sensitive on the incident angle and wavelength.

Below, I show the formulas for the dependence of the Fabry-Perot filter's reflectivity and transmitivitty coefficients on the angle of incidence courtesy of the European Journal of Physics authors Juan J Monzón and Luis L Sánchez-Soto

[image]

I am hoping to apply Dong Guoyan,et al.'s ideas which the authors wrote in this 2013 paper "Zero phase delay with relax incident condition in photonic crystals(PhC)". with the URL https://www.osapublishing.org/oe/viewmedia.cfm?uri=oe-21-24-29860&seq=0 that "Since the PhC structure can be engineered easily and have more design flexibility, it is convenient to manipulate the frequency and direction of EMW propagating in PhC with zero phase delay by changing the parameters of PhC configuration or the incident angle. Due to the prosperous nanofabrication technology, this method  for  engineered  control  of  the  phase  delay  in  PhCs  may  have  significant  potential  applications  in  chip–scale  transmission  lines,  information  processing  and  the  design  of  new  type optical devices" to building 10 degree phase delay devices.

I would like to use the transparent Indium Tin Oxide thin film multilayer structure from Christopher J.Stolz's paper Improved ITO Laser Resistance by imbedding within a Fabry Perot filter with this URL [https://www.dropbox.com/s/9h99qzwpm9z6sxd/Scans%207.4.16.pdf?dl=0]. Please remember that you have to create or use a free Dropbox account to view this paper. The reason being is that we wish to deploy such a filter above the cockpit window is to increase resistance to laser damage and minimize the angle of incidence effect where the band rejection filter spectra is shifted.

Increasing the laser resistance will reduce the life-cycle costs of installing a filter to block red, green or blue laser pointers multiple times over a 6 month period.

If you read this article, [https://news.slashdot.org/story/16/07/05/2230241/japan-says-yes-to-mirrorless-cars], Japan Says Yes to Mirrorless Cars, you realize that in a few years Japan will also say yes to planes with Planar(@TM) video displays. As a result, this topology can be installed  outside the airplane cockpit window instead of inside the interior cavity of a Boeing 757 cockpit window with 6 inch thickness.

My question is whether I can use this geometrical arrangement of optical devices to band-reject coherent laser light in an incoherent background with 30 db attenuation and 10 nanometer effective notch bandwidth while 
  1) preserving the out-of-band field of view for pilots within 100 meters of the airport 
  2) provide wide angle of incidence coverage from 0 degrees to 50 degrees.
  3) generating an output image in less than 100 microsecond time

How difficult would it be to fabricate such an 3 dimensional matrix
to meet the global demand from the aviation industry?

How might we improve upon the weaknesses in this proposed design?

Because we are sampling the interferogram  at 5 unique values of optical path difference , we do not need to find a Fabry Perot  scanning interferometers with 100 microsecond tuning speed. Please note that our 3 dimensional array of Fabry Perots and optical phase delay elements can simultaneously handle red , green and blue wavelengths stretching from 450 to 750 nm.

[image]
  [image]

Comment: There are lot of equations which have to be derived to confirm this idea.

Comment: Has anyone considered using optics simulation software packages written in C++ by http://www.zemax.com?

Comment: I made a drawing of this concept last night which I will show by midnight tonight.

Comment: This is totally not my field and you lost me at th first paragraph, but I where's the question?

Comment: I also had a hard time seeing the question. You're trying to make laserproof windows for commercial aircraft I think?

Comment: @mart, I agree with your great comment. I just revised the first paragraph and added two questions at the end. Thank you.

Comment: @andy, I agree that I did include an question initially. 5 minutes ago, I revised the first paragraph and added two questions at the end. Yes, I am trying to make laserproof windows for commercial aircraft. Thank you.

Comment: I will add a 3rd dimensional matrix tonight.

Comment: I will add a 3rd drawing tonight about self coherence of laser light

Comment: For a single source, the light can be split, delayed and recombined to 
give the self-coherence function, a complex function of the optical path difference, tau. A Fabry Perot Inteferometer can only be built to have one value of tau unless it is electro-mechanically changed.

Comment: One can avoid the issue of Fabry Perot interferometer size by using a double-wedge interferometer described in , "Compact in-line autocorrelator using double wedge" Opt. Express 20(3), 3325–3330 (2012).

Comment: @andy, To precisely answer your question about "You're trying to make laserproof windows for commercial aircraft I think?", the Boeing 757 cockpit window design will be modified. We will locate the 5 by 5 two dimensional matrix of FPI's (or double wedge interferometers) and optical phase delay elements directly above either of the top two quadrants of the Boeing 757 cockpit window. Then, the two dimensional matrix's output signal will be sent to a Planar(@TM) video display in the inner surface of a  Boeing 757 cockpit window.

Comment: @Andy, To precisely answer your question about "You're trying to make laserproof windows for commercial aircraft I think?", the Boeing 757 cockpit window design will be modified. We will locate the 3 by 5 two dimensional matrix of FPI's  and optical phase delay elements directly above the top two quadrants of the Boeing 757 cockpit window. Then, the two dimensional matrix's output signal will be sent to one of 4 Planar(@TM) video displays installed in the 4 inner surface quadrants of a Boeing 757 cockpit window.

Comment: @Dave Tweed, May I ask how I can improve the "reputation" score of this article? Thank you in advance. I know you are very busy.

Comment: @Dave Tweed, Today , I added a 3rd dimension of optical path difference for use in calculating the self-coherence function,Originally in 1999 , the self-coherence function was calculated using Michelson interferometers. Today the more compact  Fabry Perot interferometer is used to calculate the autocorrelation function. That is why we use Fabry Perot interferometers instead of Michelson interferometers in the 3D matrix block diagram.

Comment: @mart, You were right that I did not ask the right questions. I just added some big picture questions. Thank you for your observation.

Comment: @Dave Tweed, Today. I removed the extraneous 3rd dimension of optical path difference for use in calculating the self-coherence function, May I ask you to look at this URL, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1856571/how-to-find-the-system-transfer-function-corresponding-to-a-two-dimensional-matr titled How to find the system transfer function corresponding to a two dimensional matrix of optical transfer functions? Thank you.

Comment: @Dave Tweed, I just explained the weaknesses of Coutinho and Griffith's 1999 paper and furnished equations for amplitude response of Fabry Perot interferometer describing the angle of incidence dependence of Fabry Perot reflectance and transmitivitty. Now, all the pieces are in place to write a computer simulation proof of concept program.